# Win10 doesn't see changes made on HDD by Win7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs

I want to copy tens of gigabytes of data from my old Win7 computer to my new Win10 computer. By Wifi this is very slow. Hence I pulled out the Win10 HDD, plugged it into Win7, copied the data, and plugged it back. However, **Win10 doesn't see the copied files and folders** - only a few of the root folders were visible, Win10 said they are corrupted, and in a few minutes they disappeared completely.

Then I tried this again. This time I only deleted a few unimportant files from Win7. But when I plugged the HDD back into Win10, the files were still there as if I did nothing.

In older versions of Windows I was doing this routinely, and it worked.

**Q:** What prevents Win7 from making changes on a WIn10 HDD? Is it an incompatible version of NTFS? If I plugged the HDD into another *Win10* instalation, would I be able to make changes on the HDD? The HDD is not encrypted.

**Edit:** In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Interoperability), there's some info on NTFS interoperability between different Windows versions, but it's very vague. Therefore I don't know whether that info applies to my case too.

**Edit2:** I have my disk partitioned, and the problem occurs on all partitions, not only on the system partition.

I have plugged the drive into another Win10 computer. And guess what? The other Win10 saw the changes made by Win7, not the state visible by the original Win10! However, because the disk was living in this schisophrenic state for several hours, it appeared to be corrupted. The other Win10 fixed the disk, and the changes were then visible even in the original Win10.

I guess that the problem may be related to the new Win10 which is version 1903. The other Win10 is version 1709, and that seems to be compatible with the older Win7 NTFS.

Comment: *However, Win10 doesn't see the copied files and folders - only a few of the root folders were visible, Win10 said they are corrupted, and in a few minutes they disappeared completely.* You must shutdown your Windows 10 before HDD remove, not hibernate.

Comment: @akina: Of course, I did it. :-) But even when Win10 wasn't shut down properly, the changes on the disk should be visible.

Comment: For better results disable the Fast Startup feature in Windows 10 before removing the drive. Keep it disabled while you're copying files. You can later tenable it if you want.

Comment: @ GabrielaGarcia: I think I have FastStartup disabled. But anyway, the problem is not related only to the system partition, it occurs also on data partitions.

Comment: NTFS hasn’t seen changes that are incompatible with previous versions of Windows in years, this is likely a permission issue, rather then a file system incompatibility issue.  Windows 1903 NTFS is absolutely compatible with previous versions of Windows.

Comment: Is it a dual boot configuration or two different machines? If they are different machines, did you safely remove the drive? What is the procedure you followed?

Comment: @Ramhound Could you please elaborate on what you have written? Perhaps this is the cause of my problem. If this is a permission issue, how is it possible that one win installation sees something else than an another installation? And mor eimportantly, how to copy files avoiding the permission problems?

Comment: @Seth This is not a multiboot installation, but I guess that the problem would be the same as in multiboot. I just wanted to copy files from my old computer to my new computer via connecting the new disk to the old computer through USB. I have already solved my problem in another way, but I'd still like to know why connecting the disk to my old computer didn't work. I used this method many times in the past without any problems.